# Facebook Developer Account Best Practices

Tags: facebook

At my company we need to create a Facebook Developer account, but it doesn't look like we're able to do that without providing the details for an actual individual account (i.e. my personal account or that of another employee). Using a personal account doesn't make much sense (what if the person leaves the company? What if the account holder doesn't want other developers having access to their personal account? etc.) and while I know that the supreme court thinks that corporations are people it feels strange to create a fake account to associate with the company.

What do people generally do in this circumstance?

Comment: Only personal accounts can be Facebook developers. Every developer should get their personal account verified, and then be added as a developer or admin for your app. If someone leaves your company, you simply delete them from the app admins/developers. Both can be simplified by using groups.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't realized that while I create an app through an individual account the app isn't permanently bound to that account. The comment above works as an answer for me so if you post it as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Only personal accounts can be Facebook developers. Every developer should get their personal account verified, and then be added as a developer or admin for your app.

If someone leaves your company, you simply delete them from the app admins/developers.

Both can be simplified by using groups.

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate a little bit more on how groups are managed? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, that feature (of adding groups of accounts to apps) does not exist any more by now.

Comment: too bad! :( sometimes I do not understand why drives Facebook to make that kind of changes... Do you know of any other replacement feature that might come handy here?

Comment: Well I know that one of the guys at Facebook developed https://fbenroller.parseapp.com/ to help managing app roles, so maybe give that a try, it is supposed to offer bulk editing etc.

Comment: looks interesting, although I'm not 100% comfortable giving away to a third party the app secrets and ids... :(

Comment: Valid concerns. Although as I said, it is developed by an FB employee, and other people at Facebook recommended it as a replacement to deprecated/discontinued official functionality. (As far as I understand, Facebook is just not officially endorsing this app, because that would mean they’d have to support it as well; and it was born out of an internal Hackathon or something, so they probably don’t want to put additional manpower into it.)