# How to create a Facebook App for my company's game

Tags: facebook

here is the deal:
At my game studio, they want to add a Facebook Share button in one of our android game.
I know how to create a Facebook App, ie have a Developper Account. But the thing is, I don't want to create the App with my personnal account so if I leave the company they won't be able to support the Facebook App anymore. How do you guys do?

Do you create a Facebook account for the admin? Is there a way to create a company account, not a personal account, etc...

I tried creating a new account but obviously, Facebook doesn't want people to have more than 1 account...

Comment: Use your own, proper, personal account - everything else is likely to get you into trouble, and you might lose access to the app in general. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15781522/1427878

Answer (score 0):

Your Facebook account is absolutely separated from your Facebook Platform Developer Account.

You have to use your Developer Account through your user account, its liked, and your business account is more a kind of resource for managing all apps and pages.

First, you need to verify your account using phone number, so you go to:

https://developers.facebook.com/

There, you'll be able to create a developer account.
I did that for a long time, and I had not very much problems.

In fact, problems had been solved because of this.